# OpenWRT: routing LAN client with static IP to custom VPN interface

Tags: networking, routing, openwrt

On an OpenWRT router (OpenWrt 22.03.5) I've created a custom interface to connect with my WireGuard external server (WG0). 
It seems to work fine according to regular handshakes. 
There is a device connected to the router by LAN interface
with a static IP address (for example, 192.168.99.123). 
I need to route all the device's traffic through the WG0 interface
instead of the regular default WAN interface. 
Is there any relatively simple way to do it?  [LuCI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/luci.essentials) methods preferred.

Comment: This probably requires policy routing, but requires knowing how WireGuard is configured as well: can you provide its configuration? This doesn't seem to be difficult as a manual Linux setup, but I wouldn't know how LuCI handles policy routing because I don't use OpenWRT. I guess luci-app-pbr would be for this but you'd have to figure out how to do the integration.